# Django customise response for success and fail

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to create customise response for both success and fail for 1 of my serializer. Right now i only have the create function for success only

I want the output to display like the default output + my 2 other message.

promptmsg and status.

eg output of json data: if success:

promptmsg = "You have successfully create xxx"
status = '200'

if fail

promptmsg = "You have fail to create xxx"
status = '400'

Here is the code for my views

```
class ScheduleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    queryset = Schedule.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ScheduleSerializer

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            return Response({"promptmsg": "You have failed to register an account",
                             "status": "400"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        response = super(ScheduleViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.data['promptmsg'] = 'You have successfully create a book'
        response.data['statuscode'] = '200'
        return response

    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        partial = kwargs.pop('partial', False)
        instance = self.get_object()
        serializer = self.get_serializer(instance, data=request.data, partial=partial)
        if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
            return Response({"promptmsg": "You have failed to register an account",
                             "statuscode": "400"}, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

        # serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        # self.perform_update(serializer)
        response = super(ScheduleViewSet, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
        response.data['promptmsg'] = 'You have successfully create a book'
        response.data['statuscode'] = '200'
        return response
```

As you can see, if fail, it will just return the promptmsg and status only.

If success will display default response + promptmsg + status.

So how do i change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly you need to add error details to your custom error response in case of serializing failed? In this case you can use `serializer.errors` attribute:

```
if not serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
    errors_details = serializer.errors
    errors_details["promptmsg"] = "You have failed to register an account"
    errors_details["status"] = "400"
    return Response(errors_details, status=HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what i wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can inherit Response class:

```
from rest_framework.response import Response

class MyResponse(Response):
def __init__(self, data=None, status=None, headers=None,
             exception=False, content_type=None):
    # here you can create your custom fields etc...
    result = {
        'status': status,
        'message': data,
    }
    super(MyResponse, self).__init__(data=result, 
                                      headers=headers, 
                                      status=status, 
                                      exception=exception, 
                                      content_type=content_type)
```

And later just use 'MyResponse()' instead of 'Response' in views

Comment: So this more customisable ? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, here you can format the way what fields and values your json response will have